# Creating list of multiple copies from another list in python

Tags: python, numpy

Any function in numpy can achieve this? Function `f` below is kind of awkward

```
def f(l,times):
    res=[]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        res+=[l[i]]*times[i]
    return res



In  [93]:f([1,2,3],[2,2,2])

Out [93]:[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.repeat` does exactly this.
Ex:

```
In [8]: a = np.arange(4)

In [9]: b = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3])

In [10]: np.repeat(a, b)
Out[10]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

If you are working with >= 2 dimensional arrays, you can specify an axis parameter. See the doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).